# Nuitka Fails to compile with filename containing emoji

Tags: python, filenames

I have some python files in the format (start_⚡.py, enjoy_.py etc.) and i want to compile them with nuitka

i am using the following command - `python3 -m nuitka --module --no-progress --quiet --remove-output --nofollow-imports --no-pyi-file start_⚡.py`

It gives me error - `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\U0001f634' in position 41: ordinal not in range(256)`

Any solution for compiling files with emojis !?

Answer (score 1):

Emojis are not valid in python module names, so it's not surprising that nuitka doesn't handle them correctly: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement says a module name is a repetition of identifiers:

> module          ::=  (identifier ".")* identifier

where identifier is defined as

```
identifier   ::=  xid_start xid_continue*
id_start     ::=  <all characters in general categories Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nl, the underscore, and characters with the Other_ID_Start property>
id_continue  ::=  <all characters in id_start, plus characters in the categories Mn, Mc, Nd, Pc and others with the Other_ID_Continue property>
xid_start    ::=  <all characters in id_start whose NFKC normalization is in "id_start xid_continue*">
xid_continue ::=  <all characters in id_continue whose NFKC normalization is in "id_continue*">

The Unicode category codes mentioned above stand for:

    Lu - uppercase letters

    Ll - lowercase letters

    Lt - titlecase letters

    Lm - modifier letters

    Lo - other letters

    Nl - letter numbers

    Mn - nonspacing marks

    Mc - spacing combining marks

    Nd - decimal numbers

    Pc - connector punctuations

    Other_ID_Start - explicit list of characters in PropList.txt to support backwards compatibility

    Other_ID_Continue - likewise
```

(https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier). Neither⚡nor  are in those unicode categories, they are in the "Symbol, other" category.